# A question about the number of infinities.

Tags: calculus, infinity

if there are infinite whole numbers, and there are infinite decimals between 0 and 1, and there are infinite decimals between 0.1 and 0.12, and there are infinite decimals between 0.1111111 and 0.1111112, and (etc.) does that mean that there are infinitely infinite infinitely infinite infinitely infinite infinitely infinite infinitely… (etc.) infinities?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The question is quite vague. Yes, there are different infinities. And I think you could define as many as you need. So I think yes, there are infinite infinities.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Did you mean *infinitely many* when you typed *infinite*?

Comment: All the infinities you have mentioned, except for the first one, are equal.

Comment: There are infinitely many infinities, but your argument is not sufficient to show this.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One can see this via [Cantor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_theorem): given a set $A$, the set of subsets of $A$ (the power set, $\mathcal{P}(A)$) has a strictly larger cardinality. (Of course, understanding what this means and why it holds requires some background in set theory.)

Hence, you achieve an infinite chain of infinite cardinals: if $|S|$ denotes the cardinality of $S$, and if $S$ is some infinite set (e.g. the integers or real numbers), then
$$\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathcal{P}(#1)}
|S| < | \P{S} | < | \P{\P{S}} |< | \P{\P{\P{S}}} |< | \P{\P{\P{\P{S}}}} | < \cdots
$$

Comment: I would argue that this answer is incorrect, because the actual question is "... does that mean that ...", which is a non sequitur.